# regular expression that starts with an underscore but not contains any underscore

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I am trying to fetch the name of a file without the part from the last underscore until the end.

For example, 
`ABC_AA.xml` should be `ABC`
and
`ABC_AASD_AD_AA.xml` should be `ABC_AASD_AD`

I am thinking about using non-greedy with exlusive `^` symbol. 
I have tried this:

```
String nameToSearch = testName.replaceAll("_(^(_).)+\\.xml$", "");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using simple substring instead of regex

```
String nameToSearch = testName.substring(0, testName.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

or in case there can be no `_` you can use

```
String noSuffix = testName.substring(0, testName.lastIndexOf('.'));//remove ".xml" 
String nameToSearch  = noSuffix.substring(0, testName.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

---

But if you really want to use regex then you can try with

```
testName.replaceAll("_[^_]*[.]xml$", "");
```

which will match (and remove) `_` which has zero or more non `_` characters `[^_]*` and ends with `.xml`.

In case there can be no `_` you can make `_[^_]*` optional with

```
testName.replaceAll("(_[^_]*)?[.]xml$", "");
```

Comment: These don't behave identically in the case of a string with no `_`.

Comment: @ColinDeClue True. Thanks for pointing this. I updated my answer a little to handle these case.

Comment: If there are no underscores, the regex `_[^_]*` won't match, and `replaceAll()` will return the original string.  You don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

Use groups and back-references, as such:

```
String input = "ABC_AASD_AD_AA.xml";
//                       | using replaceAll to pass regex
//                       |           | group 1: one or more characters, greedy
//                       |           |   | underscore
//                       |           |   || one or more characters, reluctant
//                       |           |   ||  | escaped dot and extension
//                       |           |   ||  |         | back-reference to group 1
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(.+)_.+?\\.xml", "$1"));
```

**Output**

```
ABC_AASD_AD
```

**Note**

Any input not conforming to the `Pattern` will be returned as such.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this regex should work:

```
String repl = str.replaceFirst("_[^_]+$", "");
```

Comment: This is equivalent if we know that `str` ends in `.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` character can be used as "exclusive", i.e. to exclude certain characters, **only** as the first character of a character class inside `[]`.  `[^_]` matches any character that's not an underscore.  Outside of square brackets, it means "the beginning of the source string".

So you're close.  Try this:

```
String nameToSearch = testName.replaceAll("_[^_]+\\.xml$", "");
```

Or, if you want to handle file names *ending* in underscore (i.e. change `ABC_.XML` to `ABC`), and remove the underscore in that case, change `+` (1 or more) to `*` (0 or more).